# location aware Android, comparing distance in java or database?

Tags: java, android, mysql, geolocation

I have a question about geopoints guys..

I'm implementing a location-aware client-server application in android. Clients have some saved locations in the server database (mysql). And they will get some messages bound to these locations.

I have to compare distance between 2 points, what is the best way to store and calculate the distance. Calculating the dinstance in the database with query, 
or geting all results into server java, and then calculate 2 points which is supplied by Location.distanceBetween(..).

Which way is better, i'm a newbie in this. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Calculate the distance in the database with query then you should go through all the rows in databse... and calculate the distance from each point in that row.. Or if you get all results into server, and then calculate the distance between 2 points then also you should go through all the rows of database and get the values in rows.. and then calculate the distance.. but **in second case you should get all the values in database**(i mean location values)...but **in first case only a single value**... this is the extra work you should in second case.. so.. **first way is better**... i think..

Comment: Thank you for answering, I think its better way too.. So,Locations storage in integer degree form or lat lon form for efficient query?